# Label is displayed above the markers - MarkerWithLabel

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-markers

Javascript (see MarkerWithLabel docs)

```
var marker1 = new MarkerWithLabel({
           position: homeLatLng,
           draggable: true,
           raiseOnDrag: true,
           map: map,
           labelContent: "$425K",
           labelAnchor: new google.maps.Point(22, 0),
           labelClass: "marker", // the CSS class for the label
           labelStyle: {opacity: 0.75}
         });
```

CSS:

```
.marker {
    color: #fff;
    font-size: 16px;
    line-height: 23px;
    min-width: 36px;
    text-align: center;
    white-space: nowrap;
}
```

See the screenshot please  - https://i.stack.imgur.com/YM0Uq.jpg
Labels are always in front of a markers.

[JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/7vpm0fbu/8/)

Is it possible to fix it? Thank you.

Comment: do you have any custom css applied? if so, can you include that?

Comment: @Todd, added, nothing special, just text's styles.

Comment: The [posted code doesn't reproduce](http://jsfiddle.net/7vpm0fbu/) the behavior in the image.

Comment: @geocodezip, http://jsfiddle.net/7vpm0fbu/8/ Labels are always in front of a markers

Comment: You might need to modify the library to change the [map pane](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/reference#MapPanes) that the label is attached to.

Comment: @geocodezip Ok, let me try. Thank you for this tip!

Comment: Please post you solution as an answer and [accept it](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In `MarkerWithLabel.js`:

Find this:

```
this.getPanes().overlayImage.appendChild(this.labelDiv_);
  this.getPanes().overlayMouseTarget.appendChild(this.eventDiv_);
  // One cross is shared with all markers, so only add it once:
  if (typeof MarkerLabel_.getSharedCross.processed === "undefined") {
    this.getPanes().overlayImage.appendChild(this.crossDiv_);
    MarkerLabel_.getSharedCross.processed = true;
  }
```

Change to:

```
this.getPanes().markerLayer.appendChild(this.labelDiv_);
  this.getPanes().overlayMouseTarget.appendChild(this.eventDiv_);
  // One cross is shared with all markers, so only add it once:
  if (typeof MarkerLabel_.getSharedCross.processed === "undefined") {
    this.getPanes().markerLayer.appendChild(this.crossDiv_);
    MarkerLabel_.getSharedCross.processed = true;
  }
```

Comment: sorry i dont use js that often; can you hint me on how to do that inside the min.js from github?

Answer (score 0):

interesting. I'm thinking it could've been a js issue before. Anyway, with the styles, you can def simplify:

```
.marker {
    color: #fff; 
    text-shadow: 1px 1px 1px #000;
    font-size: 16px;
    white-space: nowrap; /* not even sure you need; depends on content... */
}
```

Comment: Unfortunately, it can't help me in my case.